# iPhone - Send VPN traffic for a specific URL

Tags: iphone, security, vpn

I am building a iPhone web based app for our execs to view sales data. The app goes over SSL with a typical login page that sets a cookie for the day.

Since the info is sensitive and we have a VPN at work I was hoping as a double precaution I could send all communications with this app over our VPN.

Is there a way I can route traffic over the VPN only for a specific URL? Does anyone have any more info on the "Send All Traffic" in the VPN configuration

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app has very little control over the VPN. A properly configured HTTPS site (particularly employing bi-directional certificates) will give you the kind of protection you're looking for your application.

That said, I strongly advocate that business users send all data over the VPN in all cases. This eliminates a wide variety of attacks and provides the opportunity for additional monitoring and protection. Thus, I generally recommend using the "Send All Traffic" VPN configuration. This would allow you to move the app entirely internal, so that outsiders cannot access the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Properly done HTTPS should be sufficient.  Provision the phone with a client certificate (there's a tool for that) and ensure the server checks them... and use a revocation list on the server side in case of stolen phones.

Comment: We already have a regular certificate through a CA that we use for SSL for our main website. Are you saying that it would be better to have a self-signed certificate for this purpose?

Comment: Self-signed would be OK, or you could purchase a signing cert.  In either case, the important thing is that each phone have a unique client cert that you can revoke, and that the server checks those certs against the revocation list.

Answer (score 1):

Making settings and managing the VPN routers and servers in iPhone is not easy. You should to make some HTTPS settings for this. After this, the client will be able to access your computer. Otherwise [iphone vpn](http://www.bestvpn.co.uk/iphone-vpn-and-why-vpn-for-iphone-is-necessary/) will lose its goal to run the server.